# Access query using java

Tags: java, ms-access

So I have the `CodeSection` field from the table `Professeur` and try to get the field `Nom` from the table `Software`.

My DB is like that :

```
Hum ...apparently I don't have enough reputation to post a picture ... I can send it to you by message
```

My query is the following :

```
String query ="SELECT Software.Nom 
        FROM Software
        WHERE Software.CodeSoftware = UtilisationSoftware.CodeSoftware 
        AND UtilisationSoftware.IdAnneeEtude = AnneeEtude.IdAnneeEtude 
        AND AnneeEtude.CodeSection = '" + codeSection + "'";
```

Where `codeSection` is a String

But the problem persists in the query

Comment: umm... aren't you missing a `from` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SELECT statement needs to have FROM keyword:

```
SELECT <...> FROM <...> WHERE <...>
```

From part should contain table names, from which you are selecting the date